# C# console reference use on windows form application project

Tags: c#

I am Learning C#, but when i was trying to do a reference on a windows form application using a console code, the error The type or namespace name 'TidPunkt' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Posting reference code below, then the Desinger.cs

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class TidPunkt
    {
        int tim, min, sek;
        bool VisaSek = true;

        public void Sätt(int t, int m, int s)
        {
            if (t >= 0 && t < 24 && m >= 0 && m < 60 && s >= 0 && s < 60)
            {
                tim = t; min = m; sek = s;
            }
            else
                Console.WriteLine("Felaktig tidpunkt");
            }
        }

        public void SättVisaSek(bool visa)
        {
            VisaSek = visa;
        }

        public int AvLäsTim()
        {
            return tim;
        }

        public int AvläsMin()
        {
            return min;
        }

        public int AvläsSek()
        {
            return sek;
        }

        public void Ticka()
        {
            if (++sek == 60)
            {
                sek = 0; ++min;
            }
            if (min == 60)
            {
                min = 0; ++tim;
            }
            if (tim == 24)
            {
                tim = 0;
            }
        }

        public override string ToString()
        {
            string tid = tim + ":" + min;
            if (VisaSek)
                tid = tid + ":" + sek;
            return tid;
        }
    }
}
```

Thats the reference code. posting the "Klockvisare.cs" code.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace WindowsFormsApplication1
{
    public partial class Klockvisare : Form
    {
        TidPunkt tp = new TidPunkt();

        public Klockvisare()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            DateTime dt = DateTime.Now;
            tp.Sätt(dt.Hour, dt.Minute, dt.Second);
            a.Text = tp.ToString();
        }

        private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            tp.Ticka();
            a.Text = tp.ToString();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Someone has edited your question to cleanup the indenting of your source code. I couldn't make heads or tails of your original. and you will get a better response from the community in the future if you make sure your post looks good. Welcome to stackoverflow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Be sure your assembly is referenced in the second project.
2. Add `public` before `class TidPunkt`
3. Add this to your second file

   ```
   using ConsoleApplication1;
   ```

Anyway, you should create a `Class Library` project and put there your first file logic (without the `Console.WriteLine`). Then you create another project, let's say a WinForm like you did, and you add the previous assembly as reference. After you import the appropriate namespaces you can use the types of the class library.

Comment: Are these files in different assemblies? If so add first a reference to the assembly

Comment: and how do i add a reference?

Comment: If you have a solution with two projects, go to the second and you will see there's a References "folder". Click "Add Reference...", select the "Projects" tab and there should be the assembly of the first project.

Comment: Look [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc668164(v=vs.100).aspx), insted of a web app create a WinForm.

Comment: Thanks! i forgot to name the label a, and to add
using ConsoleApplication1; to it.

Answer (score 2):

Change `class TidPunkt` to `public class TidPunkt`.

Comment: Have you also put `using ConsoleApplication1;` as Tomek suggested?

Answer (score 0):

You have to add your ConsoleApplication1 reference to your winforms application. If it's in another solution, then you have to add the ConsoleApplication1 dll to the references (right click on the references, then browse the dll). If it's in the same solution, then you have to right click on the references again, choose Solution option, then choose the ConsoleApplication1. After these, you can just use the "CTRL" + "." combination on the TidPunkt class and Visual Studio will find the correct namespace for you.